# Dynamic creating button using j query and displaying text on button

Tags: jquery

i am creating a button using J query like this

```
$('<input>', {
                'type': 'button',
                'text': 'Connect',
                'id':   'buttonId',
                'class': 'buttonClass',
                'style':  '1px solid red',
            }).appendTo('#myAppendToElement');
```

But it is not displaying the connect text on button. What I am missing.

Comment: you need value attribute.

Comment: You will need `value` attribute and in `style`, you need to use `border:1px solid red;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a button `input` the text on the button comes from the `value` property:

```js
$('<input>', {
  'type': 'button',
  'value': 'Connect',
  'id':   'buttonId',
  'class': 'buttonClass',
  'style':  'border: 1px solid red',
}).appendTo('#myAppendToElement');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myAppendToElement"></div>
```